# Position absolute divs on the same distance between each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a relative positioned container with many absolute positioned divs inside. I need to position the inners div in the way they are on the same distance between each other using CSS 'left' property.

I can achieve by setting fixed left values to each of them, but prefer to use a function which calculates it regardless how many inner divs a have.

So the desired result is illustrated on the picture below and following by the code I have at the moment. Basically I've just stuck with calculations :)

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="bubbles-container" populate-bubbles></div>
```

CSS

```
#bubbles-container{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
}
.bubble {
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   bottom: 0;
   border-radius: 10px;
   height: 15px;
   width: 15px;
}
```

JS/ANGULAR

```
app.directive('populateBubbles', [function(){
    return function(scope, element, attr){
        console.log(element);
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            element.append('<div class="bubble bubble' + i + '"></div>');
        }

        element.find('.bubble').each(function(){
            var bubbleLength = $(this).length;
            var bubbleWidth = $(this).width();
            var containerWidth = element.width();

            ...
        })
    }
}])
```

Comment: bubbleleft=(containerwidth-bubblewidth*bubblenumber)/(bubblenumber+1)

Comment: Why do you have to use absolute? You could make a wrapper with absolute positioning, and position the bubbles statically with some margins. No JS needed. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwGJdp

Comment: Why do you "*need to use the `left` property*"? I haven't tested, but wouldn't `display: inline-block;` (for the inner `<div>` elements) and `text-align: center;` (for the outer `<div>`) work just as well? I can't say for sure, since I haven't tested that approach, but it feels like you're over-complicating your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really cannot use flexbox, here is an other solution using

```
display: table;
display: table-cell;
```

Which is compatible with IE10.
-> https://jsbin.com/gepufuy/6/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Yes, this one does exactly what I want :) Thanks dude!

Answer (score 3):

Do not bother you with absolute positions, use flex. You won't have to calculate :

```
#bubbles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Look at this -> https://jsbin.com/gepufuy/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: It's a good solution but it doesn't work in IE10 which I still would like to support.

Comment: Too bad for you :) but i am sure you can manage it.
Look at the known issues http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can try something like this:

```
var i = 0;
var container_width = $('#bubbles-container').width();
var bubble_number = $('.bubble').length;

$('.bubble').each(function() {

    var left_space = (container_width / bubble_number) * i;
    $(this).css({left: left_space + 'px'});

    i++;
});
```